# Use Jquery to add commas to text input and prefix £

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, replace

I'm looking for a way to prefix a `£` in an input text field but also add commas for number formatting. I've got working functions for both but together they alter each other and don't work.

Working code to prefix `£`:

```
$("#income").keydown(function(e) {
    var oldvalue=$(this).val();
    var field=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(field.value.indexOf('£') !== 0) {
            $(field).val(oldvalue);
        } 
    }, 1);
});
```

Working code for commas:

```
// Add comma to input field
$('#income').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c40bvpo1/1/

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the symbol `£` in the beginning of `return`:

```js
// Add comma to input field
$("#income").keyup(function(event) {
  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return "£" + value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="income" type="text" value="£" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using one event `keydown` or `keyup`. For demonstration I've used `keyup` event.

```js
$('#income').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    let val = $(this).val(); 
    val = format_number(val);
    val = prefix_currency(val);
    
    $(this).val(val);
});

function prefix_currency(val, cur = '£' ) {
    if(val.indexOf(cur) !== 0) {
        val = cur + val;
    }
  
    return val;
}

function format_number(val) {
    return val
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="income" type="text" value="£" />
```